# Error : Vagrant Up Ubuntu

Tags: vagrant

On running Vagrant UP command getting below error message, Although Virtualization option is enable in BIOS.

Error Message :

> There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
>   for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: `["startvm", "fd5f5cf9-6d7c-48dc-bcdf-94e4f5bd85d0", "--type", "headless"]`

Stderr: VBoxManage: error: VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole

Comment: This is called nested visualization which is not supported.(eg. Host -> Guest [Ubuntu 14.04-64bit] -> Guest [Ubuntu ?-32bit]).

Comment: disable the multi-core processing and try again

Comment: @rohanKhude - > i disabled it , but it didn't worked.